# PermissionsAndroid request function returns denied

Tags: android, react-native

Executing the function bellow always return granted === denied. 
Does anyone have any suggestion how to resolve this problem ?

- By the way I'm using an Android emulator
- Permission in manifest is already set

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
  ```

Code:

```
    const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        "android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS",
        {
          title: "MyApp notifications Permission",
          message:
            "MyApp needs your permission to send you " + "notifications .",
          buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
          buttonPositive: "OK",
        },
      );

      console.log("granted", granted);
      //granted is denied always whether i click "OK" or "Ask me Later", why is that?
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        dispatch({
          type: "NOTIFICATIONS_STATUS",
          value: true,
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Notifications permission denied");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I think "android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" shouldn't be a string and it should be `PermissionsAndroid.request(android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS`...

Comment: thanks for your feedback , when i do that an error show up, saying "permission" is null

Comment: oh, yup, also it should be about PermissionsAndroid that constant: `PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS`...

Comment: this is what i get after doing what you suggest
https://prnt.sc/Z9xudZZpvlQf

Comment: sorry, it seems that one is without the final S: `PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATION` or use a version >= 0.70.7 check this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36141

Comment: yep, updating react-native fixed that,  the prompt message is showing again , but the result are the same , granted is denied, doesn't matter what button i click. im start to wonder if the request actually can change the notification status or it just shows the current state of notifications

Comment: Android version of used device? <13?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to see two dialogs. One is coming from react and contains the strings you entered (title/message/buttonNeutral/...). It is called a rationale. Then if you press "accept" or something similar there has to follow a dialog from the system which really decides if your app will get the permission. The texts of this system dialog cannot be changed.

It is good practice and [recommanded by the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#workflow_for_requesting_permissions) (step 5) that you show
a message (called a "rationale") if necessary before really requesting permission. This rationale explains why you want this permission from the user. That is why there are two prompts.

If this system dialog is not showing up that means you have rejected notification permission in the past. You have to go to `Settings > Apps > [your app] > Permissions > Notifications` and manually allow this permission once you have rejected it.

You can also request permission without showing a rationale like this:

```
PermissionsAndroid.request("android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS");
```